# Continuous subform to display already stored values MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013, subform, continuous-forms

I've been struggling with a continuous subform and it would be great if someone can give me a hand.

I have a main form "frmMain", which has record source = tblOrders ([ID], which is the primary key, and others not relevant to the question) and a subform inside it "sbfrm1" which is continuous and has record source = tblProduction ([ID], which is the primary key, [OrderID], [WeightProduced], [Time], [Date]). The subform has Link Master Field = lbOrders and Link Child Field = OrderId.

lbOrders is a listbox that displays all orders and is bound by [ID] of tblOrders. When clicked, it picks the ID of the order and the continuous form is supposed to display all stored produced weight values for that order and give the ability to add new records. However, I'm getting a blank continuous form and I'm able to fill many values and they are stored nicely in tblProduction. But when I select the order again after restarting the main form, I can't see any of those existing, it always starts over(the values exist in the table, but not shown in the cont. form).

How can I have all stored values for the OrderID I pick with lbOrders and still get a blank last column to add more?

Ah, the continuous form "sbfrm1" has only the fields [OrderID], [WeightProduced], [Time], [Date], where only WeightProduced is being populated, the OrderId is what is picked in lbOrders and the time/date are not editable, directly from system. The [ID] of the tblProduction is not present in the subform.

Can someone give me a hint to what I've done wrong in this scheme?

Comment: Simply turning off the AutoResize feature did the job...

Answer (score 1):

And the solution is to simply turn off the AutoResize feature, which obviously prevents the loading of already existing records....